# svn2git broken pipe error

Tags: perl, svn2git

I use [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) but it fails always on the same line:
My command:

```
svn2git https://my-svn/proj/ --revision 1000:1001 --username xxx
```

After one houre this command stoped running and it fails with:

```
Broken pipe at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/SVN/Ra.pm line
623.
```

What would cause this issue?

Comment: Something on the network doesn't reply. Could be a timeout from the SVN server. It's not a Perl problem, but one of the systems that program is talking to.

Answer (score 0):

For a one-time migration `git-svn` is **not** the right tool for conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are plenty tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

The `svn2git` tool you use is based on `git-svn` and thus suffers from most of the same drawbacks.

You will be easily able to configure `svn2git`s rule file to produce the result you want from your current SVN layout and you can also tell it to keep empty directories by giving it a commandline option that causes it to put empty `.gitignore` files in the directories to keep them.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` (or the `svn2git` you used) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

You see, there are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the "broken pipe" error is due to a problem receiving a file. It might be really big or there may be something else odd about it.

If you run into the error, fortunately in most cases you can simply re-run the `git svn clone` command or other related command and usually it can seamlessly resume from where it left off.

If you are using `git-svn` to do a one time migration of an SVN repo to Git, just be sure to follow [Atlassian's guide](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview). They have a tool for properly converting the SVN tags to Git tags, but it is a destructive process and you won't be able to use the git repo to sync with SVN anymore, so only do this when you're finally ready to abandon the SVN repo.